# How to run a post script in npm that is aware of exit code

Tags: npm

I'd like to run a post script in `NPM RUN` that would know if the script failed.

Right now, the behaviour of a post script is that it runs if the main script succeeded. So I can do something `on success`.

However, I want to also run the script `on failure`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I too looked for an answer to this question and the best I could do is use a bash script to always run the post command.  Here is my `npmbash`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Use this to catch control-c and cleanup.  Won't run on Windows except in git bash or similar.
#
# Pass args you'd normally pass to npm - eg. npm run dev
#   - if the args contain 'dev' or 'test' then the mongodb will be started up and shut down 
#   after it completes or control-c is pressed.

isDevOrTest=false

setIsDevOrTest() {
    for i in "$@";
    do
        if [[ $i =~ "dev|test" ]] 
        then
            echo "has dev or test"
            isDevOrTest=true
        fi
    done
}

# Trap control-c
trap 'ctrl_c' INT

function ctrl_c() {
    shutdown
    exit 0
}

function shutdown() {
    echo shutdown isDevOrTest: $isDevOrTest
    if [[ $isDevOrTest ]]
    then
        echo Its dev or test so shut down mongo
        mongo admin --eval 'db.shutdownServer()'
    fi
}

function startup() {
    echo startup
}

function run() {
    echo npm "$@"
    npm "$@"
}

setIsDevOrTest "$@"
startup
run "$@"
shutdown
```

To help keep as much in `npm` you could execute the post script you've defined to run after the main script (eg. `poststart` to the `start`):

```
function shutdown() {
    npm run poststart
}
```

But you'd need to make sure in the case of success that you only run the postscript once (eg. `poststart` by default in `npm` runs after `start` - similarly `prestart` runs before it - https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).  Should be as simple as:

```
function shutdown() {
    if [[ "$?" != "0" ]]
    then
        # Only run if previous command was not successful
        npm run poststart
    fi
}
```

Run with:

```
npmbash run dev
```